Show local extr of function is global one.
Let $f = (x^2+y^2) \exp(-x^2-y^2)$. Find global extremums.
Put $u = \exp(-x^2-y^2)$
$f_x = 2xu - 2xu(x^2+y^2) = 0$
$f_y = 2y*u - 2y*u*(x^2+y^2) = 0$
As $u \neq 0$ we have $2x(1 - x^2 - y^2) = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0$ or $1-x^2-y^2 = 0 $
When $x=0$ we have $2y(1-y^2)=0 \Rightarrow y=0, y=\pm 1$
When $1-x^2-y^2 = 0$ we have $x =\pm \sqrt{1-y^2} \Rightarrow y = 0$ and $x=\pm1$
Then find Hessian matrix: $H(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}
-4x^2+2-6x^2+4x^4-2y^2+4x^2y^2 & -4xy + 4x^3y+4xy^3+4xy  \\
-4xy + 4x^3y+4xy^3+4xy & 2-4y^2-2x^2+4x^2y^2+6y^2+4y^4  \\
\end{pmatrix}$
Thus:
$H(0,0) = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0  \\
0 & 2  \\
\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow (0,0) - $ is local min.
$H(0, \pm 1) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0  \\
0 & 8  \\
\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow (0, \pm1) -$aren't extr.
$H(\pm 1, 0) = \begin{pmatrix}
-4 & 0  \\
0 & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow (\pm 1 , 0) - $aren't extr.
Question: How can I show that (0,0) is global min?

$f(0) = 0 \leq f(x,y)$ for all other $(x,y)$ just by looking at $f.$

Don't use $*$ for multiplication. $2xu$ is fine, or you can use \cdot

"When $1-x^2-y^2 = 0$ we have $x =\pm \sqrt{1-y^2} \Rightarrow y = 0$ and $x=\pm1$": no. We have a global maximum at each point of the unit circle.

You don't need so many computations. By composition, simply look for the global extremums of $[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R,;t\mapsto te^{-t}$.

@AnneBauval, "We have a global maximum at each point of the unit circle." but points $(\pm 1, 0) , (0, \pm 1)$ aren't even local extremums, how can they be global ones or each point of the unit circle except those? Am I mistaken somewhere?

They are global (hence local) maxima, which proves that $H(0, \pm 1) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0  \
0 & 8  \
\end{pmatrix} \not\Rightarrow$"$ (0, \pm1) -$aren't extr.", and $H(\pm 1, 0) \ne\begin{pmatrix}
-4 & 0  \
0 & 0  \
\end{pmatrix}$.
